# How to make parallel requests in Ruby

Tags: ruby, concurrency, future

My question basically is... how can I make a list of requests in parallel.

Imagine that I have a list of carriers and for each carrier I need to make a quotation through an API, but in parallel.

So if I have an array of N carriers I want to make N requests and once all of them are done I want to make an action or render something.

Today what I'm doing is using **Concurrent::Future** but didn't manage to make it fire in parallel and after it finishes all carriers only then return the function:

```
    quotations = []
    carriers.each do |carrier|
        quotationOperation = Concurrent::Future.execute { 
            quote(product, carrier) #quote makes an http request and returns the JSON
        }
        quotations.push(quotationOperation.value)
    end
    puts " FINISHED JOB WITH #{quotations.count}"
```

This solutions is firing the requests sequentially

Comment: Can this be done asynchronously? If so, something like Sidekiq is your best bet.

Comment: Hmm... not actually... this is an API that will try to calculate the possible quotation to a given set of carriers

Answer (score 0):

What I actually did is

```
        operations = []
        carriers.each do |carrier|
            quotationOperation = Concurrent::Future.new { 
                quote(product, carrier) #quote makes an http request and returns the JSON
            }
            operations.push(quotationOperation)
        end

        operations.map(&:execute)
        quotations = operations.map(&:value)
```

and problem solved! All requests are being fired in parallel and only once all of them finished the function continues what it's doing

Comment: You can clean this up by doing `quotations = carriers.map { |carrier| Concurrent::Future.execute { quote(product, carrier) } }.map(&:value)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue to me seems that you call `value` during iteration. This makes the whole thing sequential again.

The [documentation](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/master/Concurrent/Future.html) says the following:

> Retrieving the value of a `Future` is done through the `#value` (alias: `#deref`) method. **Obtaining the value of a `Future` is a potentially blocking operation. When a `Future` is *:rejected* a call to `#value` will return `nil` immediately. When a `Future` is *:fulfilled* a call to `#value` will immediately return the current value. When a `Future` is *:pending* a call to `#value` will block until the `Future` is either *:rejected* or *:fulfilled*.** A *timeout* value can be passed to `#value` to limit how long the call will block. If `nil` the call will block indefinitely. If `0` the call will not block. Any other integer or float value will indicate the maximum number of seconds to block.

Moving the `value` call outside the initial iteration should fix your issue.